# Hibernate: shuffling child nodes in a bidirectional ordered tree

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, tree, hbm

I have a basic tree structure composed of a simple `Node` class, linking bidirectionally to it's single parent *(can be null for root nodes)* and an ordered list of children:

```
public class Node {
    private Integer xid;
    private Node parent;
    private List<Node> children;
    // getters and setters...
}
```

I map this using hibernate to the following simple database table:

```
 > select * from node;
 xid | parent | xorder 
-----+--------+--------
   1 |   NULL |      0
   2 |      1 |      0
   3 |      1 |      1
   4 |      1 |      2
(4 rows)
```

Using the following `.hbm` hibernate mapping file:

```
<class name="Node" table="node">
    <id name="xid" type="int">
        <generator class="native" />
    </id>
    <many-to-one name="parent" />
    <list name="children" table="node">
        <key column="parent" />
        <list-index column="xorder" />
        <one-to-many class="Node" />
    </list>
</class>
```

However, when I try to shuffle elements order within one parent using the following code:

```
@Transactional
public void testNode() {
    Node parent = (Node) getSession().get(Node.class, 1);
    Node child0 = parent.getChildren().remove(0);
    parent.getChildren().add(1, child0); // Swap first and second child
    getSession().update(parent);
}
```

I get an exception when hibernate flush the transaction: (`org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException ... set parent=null, xorder=null where parent='1' and xid='2'`): basically the update try to set `xorder` to `null`, which is obviously forbidden by the database schema.

I tried many combination on the hbm mapping, with no success. When I set the `<list>` to `inverse="true"` hibernate does not do any update, setting `insert="false" update="false"` on the `<many-to-one>` element does not help neither.

I probably miss something here, either in the `hbm` mapping or in my code, my feeling is that it should be pretty obvious... Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

[update]

Previous answer was incorrect.  I thought the constraint violation was because of parent being set to null and that sorting would avoid that.  Since the problem is with the xorder field, I think that before you update, you will need to manually go through the list and make sure that for each item in the list, the xorder field of each node matches the order of that item in the list.

For example, when you pulled the test list, you may have had 3 nodes.  For the item 0 in the list xorder=0, the item 1 has xorder=1, item 2  has xorder=2.  If you reorder those nodes in the list (for example swapping 0 and 1, you should make sure that you change the new item 0 xorder value from 1 to 0 and the node which is now item 1 should have xorder of 1.

Either that or create a new fresh children list with the nodes in the right order and set the children property to the new list.

[previous]

How about doing something like

```
Collections.sort(parent.getChildren(), new MyComparator());
```

Now all you have to do is write a Comparator implementation that makes the sorting changes you want.  I think this would avoid the constraint violation where parent gets set to null on remove.

Comment: Well, the problem here is that I can't easily use a Comparator, the shuffling is done by a user which rearrange elements. Anyway the strange thing is that the child element still have it's parent set after moving it, so I do not think the problem is related to that.

Comment: Well, the trick here is that I _do not have access_ to the `xorder` field in my java class: it's taken over by Hibernate (see `list-index` definition), that's one of its added value. In fact I already have a working solution removing the `list-index`, adding the `xorder` field in the java class and taking care of the index management myself, but I'd like to have hibernate taking care of this, it's way simpler.